# Optimize performance of portletpreferences

Tags: java, class, hashmap, portlet, websphere-portal

I am planning to write a static class for the *PortletPreferences* class. Since every time I call *PortletPreferences.getValue()*, I invoke the internal portal database to get the value. I call *PortletPreference.setValue()* and *PortletPreferences.store()* to save it in the database. Every time I change the preferences there is a database call. I want to optimize the performance of my code. I am looking for help and suggestions, how I can achieve this.

I have an idea which I am not sure is correct. Can I write a static Map class to achieve this?Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks !

Comment: What [scope](http://www.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Preference_layers_and_portlet_modes_wp7) are your preferences?

Comment: For now its only for Administrator preferences.

Comment: @McDowell Can you guide me in a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on having the preferences be essentially "read only" and the same for every user then it should be fine to load them once into a map once and then always access them in memory rather than through the API.

You should be careful however if you plan on changing portlet preferences (without restarting the portlet app) or if users are allowed to set their own values for the preferences. In both of these cases the values are dynamic and should be probably be fetched every time. You don't want some one updating a preference and not seeing it have the intended affect. You also don't want one user to be working with another user's saved preference value.

Storing preferences in a Map is essentially creating a shared cache that you have to manually update instead of the letting the API do it. If the implications of such a cache are ok for your requirements then by all means go for it.